# How can I know if provided source code was used to build APK?

Tags: android, open-source, sign

***tl;dr:*** I'm wondering if there's anyway for me to ensure that the source code I (re)viewed on GitHub for an open-source project was **actually** used to build the APK I'm downloading from Google Play?

Let's say I want to find an app for encrypting files on my local Android device. There are several apps available when googling, many open-source. As I'm going to encrypt sensitive information, I'd like to ensure it's done correctly (and without bad intent), so I review the source code for the app. All looks okay, so I download the app from Google Play and start using it.

If the developer of the app wanted to, they could just offline modify the source code (in a "private build step", so to say), and inject whatever they want (send the unencrypted file content somewhere, fake-encrypt the files, whatever), build the APK and upload that APK to Google Play instead.

Is there anyway to verify the APK actually came from the source code?

Comment: I don't think that is possbile but if you have the sources you can compile the sources you reviewed.

Comment: What you are asking for is [a reproducible build](https://reproducible-builds.org/). In theory, if you compile the app yourself, and compare its unsigned contents to the APK from the Play Store, they should match. How reproducible any specific build is varies. F-Droid has this [as an objective](https://f-droid.org/docs/Reproducible_Builds/) and [is making progress](https://forum.f-droid.org/t/are-reproducible-builds-possible-now/335/3).

Comment: Yeah if you have the source code why not building the app yourself?

Comment: Yes, I understand I can build it from source, but I was wondering about Google Play/compiled APK. I think @CommonsWare had the answer I was looking for - I can make it accepted if you post it as an answer :)

Comment: IMHO, my comment doesn't really answer the question, at least with respect to the Play Store.